# Chrome extension - open multiple tabs after filling in the form

Tags: forms, google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension - when an user clicks on a icon, the popup window with the form appears. The textarea in the form can contain more parameters which comes to URL. After filling in and clicking the GO button, multiple tabs with URLs with this parameters needs to be opened.

Example: `popup.html`

```html
<form name="myform">`
<textarea id="params" name="params" style="width: 170px;height: 270px;"></textarea>`
<input id="edit" checked="checked" type="radio" name="edit" value="1" /> option 1 <input id="edit" type="radio" name="edit" value="2" /> option 2`
<div id="clicked">GO</div>`
</form>`
```

Then in `popup.js` I have:

```js
function click(e) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: "alert('starting');"
    });

    opener();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var divs = document.getElementById("red");

    divs.addEventListener('click', click);

});
```

So when an user clicks on GO button, the opener() function needs to be started.

Here is the opener function - it only determines the values of textarea and radio buttons and opens as many new tabs as manz parameters are in the textarea.

```js
function opener() {
    alert('working');
    var parameter = document.myform.getElementById("params").value;
    for (index = 0; index < document.myform.edit.length; index++) {
        if (document.myform.edit[index].checked) {
            var radioValue = document.myform.edit[index].value;
            break;
        }

        var Result = parameter.split("\n");

        if (radioValue == 1) {
            for (i = 0; i < Result.length; i++) {
                window.open('http://mypage.com?param=' + Result[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the Result is the value of textarea splitted by \n  and radio value is the value of radio button selected.

This works fine - after clicking a browser icon the popup with form comes up, but when I fill in the textarea and select the first radiobutton, then I click GO, the opener funvtion works not...

The only thing that works is the popup alert with working word and then the alert starting from the click(e) function.

So the opener function starts, writes the alert, but nothing else... no tabs will open, nothing happens...

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that using the chrome.tabs.create function works much better within the extension than the window.open function does.

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:"https://www.facebook.com/PSChrome"});
```

Comment: I think the problem was in obtaining the values from radio buttons and thats why the script stopped here. And yes, thank you, the chrome.tabs.create works very well! The only thing I want to know is - that my extension works only when any http:// page is opened in chrome, but works not on empty tab. I think it's something with the permissions set in manifest.json - "permissions": [ 
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ] but I don't know how to set it to work also on empty tabs...